# AngularJS state change using ui-router causing flickering on UI

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a very simple two page app and when navigating from listing page to details page, there is a very distinct flicker caused due to hide/show of the UI components. Attached is a screenshot where you can see both UIs visible at the time of transition (at the top is the details UI and at the bottom is the list UI)!

[image]

I am using ui-router for navigation.

`function routingConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, applicationPathProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('activities', {
          url: applicationPathProvider.getBase(),
          views: {
            '': {
              templateUrl: '/js/activity/activityList.partial.html',
              controller: 'ActivityListController',
              controllerAs: 'activityListController',
              resolve: {
                activitiesResponse: function(activityListService) {
                  return activityListService.listActivities();
                }
              },
              ncyBreadcrumb: {
                parent: '',
                label: 'Activity List'
              }
            }
          }
        })
        .state('activityDetails', {
            url : applicationPathProvider.getPath('activityDetails'),
            templateUrl : '/js/activity/activityDetails/activityDetails.partial.html',
            controller : 'ActivityDetailsController',
            controllerAs: 'activityDetailsController',
            resolve: {
                activityDetailsResponse: function($state, $stateParams, activityListService) {
                    return activityListService.getTasksForActivity($stateParams.activityId);
                }
            },
            ncyBreadcrumb: {
                parent: 'activities',
                label : '{{activityDetailsController.selectedActivityText}}'
            }
        })
    ;
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(applicationPathProvider.getBase());
  }`

Here is the service code which sends a REST call and creates a data structure which controller uses.

```
function getTasksForActivity(activityId) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  Restangular.one("activities", activityId).customGET("tasks")
      .then(function (restangularTasks) {
        deferred.resolve(buildValidTasksResponse(restangularTasks.plain()));
      }, buildErrorTasksResponse);

  return deferred.promise;

}
```

Here is the code for page 1 (the list page)

```
    <div class="sl-artefact-plans" layout="row" flex>
  <div class="sl-artefact-list-container" layout="column" style="width: 100%">
    <div class='list_table'>
      <div class='list_row' ng-repeat="activity in activityListController.activities | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse">
        <div class='list_cell overflow td'>
          <a ui-sref="activityDetails({activityId: activity.id})"
             ng-click="activityListController.setSelectedActivityInService(activity)">
            {{activity.summary}}
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class='list_cell td' ng-bind="activity.dueBy | date:'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a' : 'UTC'">
        </div>
        <div class='list_cell td' ng-bind="activity.status">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is page 2:

```
    <div class="sl_artifact_details_header_bar">
  <div class="sl_artifact_details_heading">
    {{activityDetailsController.selectedActivityText}}
  </div>
  <div class="sl_artifact_details_info">
        <span ng-class="activityDetailsController.selectedActivityStatus"
              style="vertical-align:middle; margin:0px 0px 0px -3px">
        {{activityDetailsController.selectedActivity.dueBy | date:'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a' : 'UTC'}}</span>
    <span style="padding-left: 10px">{{activityDetailsController.selectedActivity.status}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="task in activityDetailsController.tasks">
        <td ng-bind="task.summary"></td>
        <td ng-bind="task.status"></td>
        <td ng-bind="task.dueBy"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is a very simple use-case and I am quite confused as to why is this occurring and how to resolve this.

Any pointers will help. Thanks.

Comment: could it be that you're using `views: { '': {} }` in first one but not second?  (I think unless you are using multiple named views, you don't need to wrap in the `views: {}` object).   Also, are you using ng-animate at all?

Comment: I removed 'views' and tried but that didn't help. Also not using ng-animate anywhere.

Comment: can you please add your template code

Comment: Added in original question. Thanks very much for looking into this.

Comment: did you find a solution?